# How can an iOS app change a Bluetooth 4(BLE) peripheral's name?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Apparently, my iOS app cannot write to the GAP service's `gap.device_name` characteristic for my BLE device because that is a read only characteristic.

So how can this be done? Is there a standard way to do this?